# Touch Screen - No calibration devices found

Tags: touchscreen

I have just brought in a acer z3801 all in one and installed ubuntu 12.04 ltd and updated. Have installed utouch and xcalibrator. when I try to launch x-calibrator it gives the error
**Error: No calibratable devices found.**